# Android: How can i shorten a url and hyperlink it with the original url with textview?

Tags: android, url, textview, substring

I have shorten a url link in textview and i would like to make it clickable with the original url for example:

From this: https://www.google.com.sg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=xViYVuCANuPJ8Aep4qeoCQ

To this: https://www.google.com.sg

However, when i click on the link below, i would like to redirect it to the original url.

My code is below.

```
TextView view;
ArrayList<HistoryDetails> userList1 = new ArrayList<>();

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

 userList1.add(new HistoryDetails(mCur.getLong(dateIdx), mCur.getString(titleIdx),mCur.getString(urlIdx)));

 for (HistoryDetails obj : userList1) {
                if(obj.url.length()>30)
                    view.append(obj.url.substring(0,30) + "\n");
                else
                    view.append(obj.url + "\n");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the tag of the view to the complete URL. In your for loop, try:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)

```
for (HistoryDetails obj: userList1) {
    // Set the tag to save the full URL string.
    view.setTag(obj.url);

    // Now set the text.
    if (obj.url.length() > 30)
        view.append(obj.url.substring(0,30) + "\n");
    else
        view.append(obj.url + "\n");
}
```

Then set a touch listener on the URL to send an Intent to a browser, or whatever you need to do when the user touches the text.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
        // Now extract your tag from the view,
        // this will be your full URL string.
        String URL = (String) v.getTag();

        // Do what you need with it.

        // Return true to consume the touch event.
        return true;
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am quite new to android. Can i know how can i create a hyperlink out of url. I tried v.setClickable(true);
                v.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                v.setText(Html.fromHtml(URL)); but it returns with error.

Comment: Check out this article, it should point you in the direction you want to go:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html

Comment: I forgot to mention i have got a list of url and i tried printing out the string URL and it seems that it only target one of the value instead of all.